# Resizing panels in GUIs without changing size of the contents (MATLAB)

Tags: user-interface, matlab, panel

Does anyone know how to change the size of a panel in the gui editor (guide) without changing the size of the contents? At the moment, if I change the size of the panel, I have to spend three times as long changing the size of the contents, and its a real pain.

Thanks
James

Answer (score 8, accepted):

GUI components, such as buttons are only resized when you resize the GUI if their units are set to 'normalized'. Set the units to characters in the property inspector, and you should be fine (you can use the property inspector to edit multiple components at the same time).

Answer (score 1):

To make the text inside a panel resize automatically, set the fontUnits property to 'normalized'.